# Adding lines connecting labels to points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, point, expression

I'm working on a map that has a lot of points in a small area, so I'm adding lines from my labels to their points using a Geometry generator in the symbol designer.  The problem I'm having is that the lines always come from the bottom left corner of the label.

How do I get them to come from the part of the label that is closest to the point?

I'm using the following Expression and really don't have a clue where to go from there.

```
    make_line( make_point( $x,$y), make_point( "X","Y"))
```

Comment: Have you considered using the easy_label plugin?

Comment: I have tried it, and had some problems with it. it seems like it always wants to add some extra kinks in the lines. and I cant seem to get rid of them.

Comment: but you could use it's label points to draw your own line

Comment: I'll have to look into that. I'm still learning how to do some of that stuff, so don't always think of everything.

Comment: I tried that, but when I used the geometry generator I couldn't even get the lines to draw.

Comment: You could add an offset to the label placement, based on the length of the label, to line up the label with the point X,Y.

Comment: Using data-defined label offset with an expression like this:  conversionfactor*length( attribute( $currentfeature ,'labelattribute'))  where conversionfactor is a number that converts the number of characters in the label into a good distance for the offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the label alignment will change which corner of the label is located at the defined point.

[image]

### Set up data-defined label alignment

1. Add two new text fields, Align_H and Align_V
2. Fill Align_H with the desired horizontal alignment of each label: left or right. Fill Align_V with the desired vertical alignment: bottom or top.
3. Use these fields to control alignment under label properties.
   [image]

Comment: I'm getting somewhere now. I can draw a line based on a condition in the geometry generator expression area.  What i would like to do is be able to get the bounds of my label now. something like this:   'CASE
WHEN "Y" < $y THEN make_line(make_point("X", "Y_max" ),$geometry)
END'   Where "Y_Max" is the the top of the label, or "X_max" is the the right side.

Comment: If you want help getting the bounds of the label, I think that merits being a separate question.